# nginx won't load a conf file that is symlinked

Tags: nginx

I have 2 servers (new one and old one)

On both servers there is a conf file called mysite.conf that is symlinked to /var/local/mysite/conf/mysite.conf

/etc/nginx/conf.d/mysite.conf -> /var/local/mysite/conf/mysite.conf

On the old server, everything works.  However, on the new server, it won't follow the symlink.  If I make the conf file a real file, then nginx will load it /etc/nginx/conf.d/mysite.conf and it works.

What could be the difference?

File permissions are identical on the .conf files.

The main /etc/nginx/nginx.conf files are identical.

Comment: Check permissions for all parent directories

Comment: The file/directory perms are identical on both machines.  The conf files are 644 and directories down to them are 755.

Comment: It could have something to do with SELinux. There are some questions related to that

Comment: I think so too.  I can see some things in /var/log/audit/audit.log.  I used audit2why and audit2allow, created a module, installed it, but it didn't work. The other server works, but this one doesn't.  There's a clue there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.  It was SELinux.  Thank you Alexey Ten.  To cure it, you need to make a module to adjust the SELinux settings.

```
tail /var/log/audit/audit.log | audit2why
tail /var/log/audit/audit.log | audit2allow -m myapplocal > myapplocal.te
tail /var/log/audit/audit.log | audit2allow -M myapplocal 
semodule -i myapplocal.pp
```

The resulting module looks like this for me:

```
require {
    type httpd_t;
    type var_t;
    class file getattr;
}

#============= httpd_t ==============
allow httpd_t var_t:file getattr;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding to your nginx.conf file:

```
http {
    disable_symlinks off;
}
```

Comment: I believe that setting is not for following symlinks on conf files, but for following symlinks on files being served up. Nevertheless, I tried it and it didn't work.